# Winforms Ribbon интерфейс под Windows 10?

Tags: c#, winforms, ribbon

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли под Windows 10 бесплатная библиотека для C# WinForms для отображения Ribbon интерфейса?

Comment: Посмотри тут: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application

Comment: https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms